# Page goes blank in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there is a good way to troubleshoot why a page goes blank in IE ?
I know I can switch to Compatability Mode 7, but dealing with IE7 quarks is even worse.

Comment: You need to shows us the code or provide url to that page.

Comment: Validate first.  If it still doesn't work, post the URL.

Comment: It's a huge ASPX page and I can't post due to privacy issues.
I was wondering if there is a good way to go about fixing this sort of thing.

Comment: Is there html if you do view source? What does Fiddler tell you? Maybe an extra page gets fetched. Do you use object tags/hta like functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://validator.w3.org/ to determine this issue.